# DSE Cassandra Spark Error

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, apache-spark-sql

I spent the whole day trying to figure out a way to resolve this but no luck.

Each time my java application tries to connect to my DSE Spark master, It throws an error:

`Association with remote 
system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.2.104:7077] has failed, address is now 
gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].`

Tailing cassandra log, I can see an incompatibilty in the class version:

```
ERROR [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] 2015-06-09 16:39:12,066  
Slf4jLogger.scala:66 - org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local 
class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7674242335164700840, 
local
class serialVersionUID = 2812534333379744973
java.io.InvalidClassException: 
org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7674242335164700840, local class 
serialVersionUID = 2812534333379744973
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

It's a version mismatch but this is not clear as what to do to resolve it.

Am running DSE  4.7 and my POM file is like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax</groupId>
    <artifactId>dse</artifactId>
    <version>version number</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/dse-4.7.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Question is which version of cassandra connector works with DSE 4.7 ?

Comment: do you somehow have two versions of the spark jars?

Answer (score 2):

There is a version mismatch. DSE 4.7 ships with Spark 1.2.1 but you are building your jar against 1.1.1.

Comment: Right, but still blowing up! I've tried different versions in my POM file and none of it worked. I'm really sure DSE 4.7 breaks a lot of things here.

Comment: Same exception even when you are running 1.2.1 built driver against 4.7 DSE?

Comment: @phact: I can launch dse spark

Comment: @RussS: same exception...pissed off.

Comment: If DSE Spark works there must be something else going on with your build or submission that is using an old version of spark somewhere. If you want to eliminate all possibility of version incompatibility changer your pom to use the resources/spark/lib folder as spark dependencies. (There is an example of how to do this in the demo folder spark in dse) This will build against the exact same jars which DSE uses to run. Then make sure you launch with `dse spark-submit`.

Comment: @RussS, that actually worked. I can't figure out while I couldn't run it from the POM. Thanks